# What are the basic requirements for using WebSockets serverside?

Tags: asp.net, web, websocket, server-side, backend

I'm trying to learn about WebSocket as I see many possibilities with it and would like to explore it, but I am having a hard time understanding the basic requirements for it.

There exist a ton of blogs out there praising WebSocket like was it God and they explain how to develop WebSocket applications brilliantly.

However I don't understand when they all shortly mention that you need a **WebSocket compatible server** and then none of them tells you how to set it up and what you need to do to make it work properly when you call it through your client side scripts etc. - Even [WebSocket.org](https://www.websocket.org/) fails to explain it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Say I have an ASP.NET website and would like to use WebSocket to push notifications, maybe even have a chatroom. What would I need to do to make my Javascript-based chatroom application working?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET, you will need IIS8 to work with WebSockets integrated in the app (so you would need Windows 8 or Windows 2012). Or, you can have a WebSocket server in another port/server.

If your "push" requirements are not very exigent, you can try SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr. Check out their tutorials [to get started](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr). But again, you won't be able of using WebSockets unless you are using IIS8.

Other WebSocket frameworks are [XSocket.NET](http://xsockets.net/) and [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/). Or if you want you can take a look at my [WebSocketListener](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener) that I am developing, that is just a lightweight WebSocket connector and nothing more, although it is under heavy development at the moment.

From client side, the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) is the same for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and not any particular problem specific.

WS (WebSockets) is protocol that is implemented in most modern browsers and platforms, and is well consistent.

But same way as you need something to be as HTTP web server (ASP.Net + IIS, Apache + PHP, node.js, python, etc) you need similar or compatible technology for WebSockets. As it is different protocol, your technology have to support. From "recognising" traffic as WS, directing to right process via socket/proxying, handshaking, deserializing traffic into actual data, and providing you an interface to work with all of it.
So you need basically google: "%YOUR TECH/LANGUAGE% WebSockets". That will give you information on how to use WS on your platform.
You need to understand specifics that it is different protocol, so it might not be that "friendly" with some complicated infrastructure cases.

ASP.Net 4.5 do support WebSockets by default, just find documentation on how to use it in ASP.Net.

And this question would not be raised if you would try to do some experimentation and prototyping with WebSockets in first place.